# org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not load an entity

Tags: spring, hibernate, jdbc, persistence, hibernate-mapping

During the run time of my code it throws the exception-

```
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not load an entity: [com.expo.esf.model.InvoiceHouse#15566]
2013-05-27 15:41:12,852  WARN hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter:77   - SQL Error: 600, SQLState: 60000
2013-05-27 15:41:12,881 ERROR hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter:78   - ORA-00600: internal error code, arguments: [qctstc2o1], [1], [0], [0], [1], [0], [0], []
```

I don't understand the problem. My model class seems to be perfect.

This is my dispatcher-servlet.xml file-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<bean id="jspViewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>



<!-- max upload size in bytes -->
  <bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
       <property name="maxUploadSize" value="10000000"/>
  </bean>
```

Comment: it is not able to load com.expo.esf.model.InvoiceHouse class , check spring-servlet.xml , post it here or annotation in class

Comment: Ora-00600 is a generic Oracle error. Have a look at this: http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/ORA-00600. I would suggest to make hibernate log the query it tries to execute and manually execute it on the database to see the result.

Comment: @anshulkatta I've no spring-servlet.xml but I've added dispatcher-servlet.xml which is given above.

Comment: I manually executed the query and its fine. but whenever i try it with hibernate it shows the above message. @Robe Elckers

Comment: Please post trace file. try this to find trace file for your session. you will find it in $ORACLE_BASE/admin/$ORACLE_SID or following query show the path.
SQL>show parameter user_dump_dest;